# delete image after a collision on xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory, uiimageview, collision-detection

well I have two images image1 and image2. I would like to delete image1 when it collide to image2. For this , I use release but it doesn't delete it because it is still visible. I don't know how to delete it from the view and the memory. Can you help me please

Answer (score 2):

Use `[image1 removeFromSuperview]` to remove it from the view.  This will likely release the object if its retain count hits zero.